# How to scan source of a RPGLE program?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I want to scan source from a RPGLE program but there is a problem. I explain problem below.
Source is:

```
fTcsprefix if   e             disk    rename(tcsprefix:testpr)  
f                                     prefix (@)
```

I want to scan the PREFIX keyword if it exists in the source code. But when scanning it is found in the record format name. How can I avoid this?

I am using:

```
**C   'PREFIX'     SCAN    SRCDTA     S1**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try scanning for **' PREFIX'**, i.e., with a leading space. Unless you can guarantee that there is always a space after the PREFIX keyword, you can't also rely on a trailing space in the search-string. (You can try it.)

---

For more extensive testing:

If coding standards don't maintain clear syntax, you need to extend the logic. This statement finds where `PREFIX` is found:

```
 C   'PREFIX'     SCAN    SRCDTA     S1
```

It stores the location in `S1`. You can then use `S1` to test if the position before contains a blank or a ')'. If you find any other characters that are valid, the logic can be extended to test for added valid characters. Also, you know that `PREFIX` is six characters long, so you can test the character at position `S1+6` to see if it is a blank or a '(' or other valid character.

When your program finds `PREFIX` and it also finds that both the preceding and succeeding characters are acceptable, it should know that it found a match that fits.

When `SCAN` finds a match, you probably should pass the source line to a sub-procedure that tests the preceding and succeeding characters and returns an indicator value. The indicator will tell your program if it's a good match or not.

You might also consider not using `SCAN` at all. Use the `%scan()` BIF instead and use a free-form coding style.

Comment: But if PREFIX is as follows FTCSPREFIX IF E DISK RENAME(TCSPREFIX:TESTPR)PREFIX(@). Will it be scanned accurately?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the ILE C runtime regex procedures from ILE RPG.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rtref/regexh.htm%23regexh
Note that the RE library on the IBM i follows POSIX standards.
http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html

Here's an article to look at; complete with source containing the prototypes you'd need to call the functions.
http://iprodeveloper.com/rpg-programming/validate-e-mail-address-regular-expression